# Find each word in audio files

Tags: linux, terminal, speech, sox, audacity

I have watches a way of doing this with audacity by using sound finder option. But since audacity is only gui it cannot be used with terminal commands. So is there a program that does the same work but in command interface like **sox** for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sox input.wav slice.wav silence 1 1.0 2% 1 3.0 2% : newfile : restart
```

Answer (score 0):

[Currently, Audacity **does** have experimental support for scripting.](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/scripting.html)

> The scripting module is an experimental GUI plug-in that allows Audacity to be driven from an external Perl or Python script. Commands are sent to Audacity over a named pipe. Any scripting language that supports named pipes can be used. External scripting is one of several ways to extend the functionality of Audacity.

---

> Scripting support is currently considered experimental and is mainly intended for use by developers for the time being.
>   Feel free to try it out, but don't be too surprised if there are problems, or if the details of commands change between versions of Audacity.
>   Currently Windows or Linux are recommended. Mac requires more work to get anything useful at all.
>   There is a fuller list of limitations at the foot of this page.

---

Specifically, try out the ‘Menu Command’ option:
https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/scripting.html#MenuCommand